# WinSCP session via powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, permissions, hostname, winscp

I'm writing a script the send file to ftp sever.

In the ftp server I have permission to a subfolder but not to the root folder (C:).

When I'm trying to connect I received authentication error because of the permission.

When I'm trying to replace the hostname to the full path I received an connection error because this is not the right hostname.

How can I connect directly to the subfolder?

The script:

```
# config credentials
$username = "example"
$a = Get-Content -Path "example"
$sec = ConvertTo-SecureString $a -AsPlainText -force
$hostname = "ftp.xxx.co.il"

# Set credentials to a PSCredential Object.
$SessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
UserName = $username
Password = $sec
HostName = $hostname
FtpMode = [WinSCP.FtpMode]::Active
protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
FtpSecure = [WinSCP.FtpSecure]::Explicit
PortNumber = 21

}

# Create a WinSCP Session.
$session = New-WinSCPSession -SessionOption $SessionOptions

# Using the WinSCPSession, send the file from the local host to the remote host.
Send-WinSCPItem -WinSCPSession $session -Path "D:\test\*.txt" -Destination "/users/users's folder/shaon"
```

Log file from the Powershell session:

```
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.736 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.738 WinSCP Version 5.13.7 (Build 9125) (OS 10.0.14393 - Windows Server 2016 Standard)
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.738 Configuration: nul
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.739 Log level: Normal
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.739 Local account: *******
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.739 Working directory: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\winscp\bin
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.739 Process ID: 55884
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.739 Command-line: "C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\winscp\Public\..\bin\winscp.exe" /xmllog="C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\wscp21C4.0163DF7F.tmp" /xmlgroups /xmllogrequired /nointeractiveinput /dotnet=5.13.7  /ini=nul /log="c:\temp\Winscmp\Sessionlog.log"  /console /consoleinstance=_8644_38962522_480
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.740 Time zone: Current: GMT+2, Standard: GMT+2 (Jerusalem Standard Time), DST: GMT+3 (Jerusalem Daylight Time), DST Start: 26/03/2021, DST End: 31/10/2021
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.740 Login time: יום חמישי 16 דצמבר 2021 16:34:22
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.740 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.740 Script: Retrospectively logging previous script records:
> 2021-12-16 16:34:22.740 Script: option batch on
< 2021-12-16 16:34:22.740 Script: batch           on        
< 2021-12-16 16:34:22.740 Script: reconnecttime   120       
> 2021-12-16 16:34:22.740 Script: option confirm off
< 2021-12-16 16:34:22.740 Script: confirm         off       
> 2021-12-16 16:34:22.740 Script: option reconnecttime 120
< 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 Script: reconnecttime   120       
> 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 Script: open ftp://:***@ftp.***.co.il:21 -explicit -passive=0 -timeout=15
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 Session name: ***@ftp.***.co.il (Ad-Hoc site)
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 Host name: ftp.***.co.il (Port: 21)
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 User name: *** (Password: Yes, Key file: No, Passphrase: No)
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 Transfer Protocol: FTP
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 Ping type: Dummy, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 Disable Nagle: No
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 Proxy: None
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 Send buffer: 262144
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 UTF: Auto
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 FTPS: Explicit TLS/SSL [Client certificate: No]
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 FTP: Passive: No [Force IP: Auto]; MLSD: Auto [List all: Auto]; HOST: Auto
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 Session reuse: Yes
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 TLS/SSL versions: TLSv1.0-TLSv1.2
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 Local directory: default, Remote directory: home, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, Bin path: 
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 Timezone offset: 0h 0m
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.741 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.749 Connecting to ftp.***.co.il ...
. 2021-12-16 16:34:22.761 Connected with ftp.***.co.il, negotiating TLS connection...
< 2021-12-16 16:34:22.764 220 Microsoft FTP Service
> 2021-12-16 16:34:22.764 AUTH TLS
< 2021-12-16 16:34:22.768 234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
. 2021-12-16 16:34:23.064 Verifying certificate for "***" with fingerprint ------------------------------ and 20 failures
. 2021-12-16 16:34:23.065 Certificate common name "*.***.co.il" matches hostname
. 2021-12-16 16:34:23.103 Certificate verified against Windows certificate store
. 2021-12-16 16:34:23.103 Using TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3:-------------------------------------------------
. 2021-12-16 16:34:23.104 TLS connection established. Waiting for welcome message...
> 2021-12-16 16:34:23.104 USER ***
< 2021-12-16 16:34:23.107 331 Password required
> 2021-12-16 16:34:23.107 PASS ****************************
< 2021-12-16 16:34:23.112 530 User cannot log in.
. 2021-12-16 16:34:23.112 Connection failed.
. 2021-12-16 16:34:23.112 Password prompt (last login attempt failed)
```

Log file from the gui session

```
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.224 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.225 WinSCP Version 5.19.5 (Build 11933 2021-11-25) (OS 10.0.14393 - Windows Server 2016 Standard)
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.225 Configuration: HKCU\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.225 Log level: Normal
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.225 Local account: xxx
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.225 Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.225 Process ID: 2356
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.248 Ancestor processes: explorer, ...
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.248 Command-line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" 
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.249 Time zone: Current: GMT+2, Standard: GMT+2 (Jerusalem Standard Time), DST: GMT+3 (Jerusalem Daylight Time), DST Start: 26/03/2021, DST End: 31/10/2021
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.249 Login time: יום חמישי 16 דצמבר 2021 21:24:44
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.249 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.249 Session name: user@ftp.x.co.il (Ad-Hoc site)
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.249 Host name: ftp.x.co.il (Port: 21)
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.249 User name: user (Password: Yes, Key file: No, Passphrase: No)
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.249 Transfer Protocol: FTP
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.249 Ping type: Dummy, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.249 Disable Nagle: No
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.250 Proxy: None
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.250 Send buffer: 262144
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.250 UTF: Auto
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.250 FTPS: Explicit TLS/SSL [Client certificate: No]
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.250 FTP: Passive: Yes [Force IP: Auto]; MLSD: Auto [List all: Auto]; HOST: Auto
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.250 Session reuse: Yes
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.250 TLS/SSL versions: TLSv1.0-TLSv1.3
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.250 Local directory: default, Remote directory: home, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.250 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.250 Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, Bin path: 
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.250 Timezone offset: 0h 0m
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.250 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.299 Connecting to ftp.x.co.il ...
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.299 Connected with ftp.x.co.il, negotiating TLS connection...
< 2021-12-16 21:24:44.299 220 Microsoft FTP Service
> 2021-12-16 21:24:44.299 AUTH TLS
< 2021-12-16 21:24:44.300 234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.342 Verifying certificate for "x" with fingerprint ----- and 20 failures
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.342 Certificate common name "*.x.co.il" matches hostname
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.383 Certificate verified against Windows certificate store
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.384 Using TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2: -------
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423 TLS connection established. Waiting for welcome message...
> 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423 USER user
< 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423 331 Password required
> 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423 PASS ********
< 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423 230 User logged in.
> 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423 SYST
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423 The server is probably running Windows, assuming that directory listing timestamps are affected by DST.
< 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423 215 Windows_NT
> 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423 FEAT
< 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423 211-Extended features supported:
< 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423  LANG EN*
< 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423  UTF8
< 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423  AUTH TLS;TLS-C;SSL;TLS-P;
< 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423  PBSZ
< 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423  PROT C;P;
< 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423  CCC
< 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423  HOST
< 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423  SIZE
< 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423  MDTM
< 2021-12-16 21:24:44.423  REST STREAM
< 2021-12-16 21:24:44.424 211 END
> 2021-12-16 21:24:44.424 OPTS UTF8 ON
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.424 Disconnected from server
. 2021-12-16 21:24:44.424 Connection failed.
* 2021-12-16 21:24:44.450 (EFatal) Connection failed.
* 2021-12-16 21:24:44.450 Disconnected from server
* 2021-12-16 21:24:44.450 Connection failed.
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.030 Connecting to ftp.x.co.il ...
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.031 Connected with ftp.x.co.il, negotiating TLS connection...
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.031 220 Microsoft FTP Service
> 2021-12-16 21:24:49.031 AUTH TLS
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.031 234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.031 Verifying certificate for "x" with fingerprint --- and 20 failures
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.031 Certificate common name "*.x.co.il" matches hostname
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.059 Certificate verified against Windows certificate store
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.059 Using TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2: -----
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.081 TLS connection established. Waiting for welcome message...
> 2021-12-16 21:24:49.081 USER user
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.081 331 Password required
> 2021-12-16 21:24:49.081 PASS ********
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.081 230 User logged in.
> 2021-12-16 21:24:49.081 SYST
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.081 The server is probably running Windows, assuming that directory listing timestamps are affected by DST.
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.081 215 Windows_NT
> 2021-12-16 21:24:49.081 FEAT
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.081 211-Extended features supported:
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.081  LANG EN*
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.081  UTF8
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.081  AUTH TLS;TLS-C;SSL;TLS-P;
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.081  PBSZ
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.081  PROT C;P;
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.081  CCC
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.081  HOST
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.082  SIZE
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.082  MDTM
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.082  REST STREAM
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.082 211 END
> 2021-12-16 21:24:49.082 OPTS UTF8 ON
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.082 200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
> 2021-12-16 21:24:49.082 PBSZ 0
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.087 200 PBSZ command successful.
> 2021-12-16 21:24:49.087 PROT P
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.091 200 PROT command successful.
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.117 Connected
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.118 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2021-12-16 21:24:49.135 PWD
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.139 257 "/" is current directory.
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.139 Getting current directory name.
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.173 Retrieving directory listing...
> 2021-12-16 21:24:49.173 TYPE A
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.177 200 Type set to A.
> 2021-12-16 21:24:49.177 PASV
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.181 227 Entering Passive Mode (ip).
> 2021-12-16 21:24:49.181 LIST -a
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.181 Connecting to IP ...
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.187 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.423 Session ID reused
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.424 Using TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2: ----
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.424 TLS connection established
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.428 08-31-21  01:50PM       <DIR>          Customers
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.428 12-09-21  12:11PM       <DIR>          Users
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.428 Data connection closed
< 2021-12-16 21:24:49.429 226 Transfer complete.
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.429 Directory listing successful
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.429 Detecting timezone difference...
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.429 Found no file to use for detecting timezone difference
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.429 Warning: Timezone difference was not detected yet, timestamps may be incorrect
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.429 ..;D;0;1899-12-30T02:00:00.000Z;0;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.429 Customers;D;0;2021-08-31T11:50:00.000Z;1;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.429 Users;D;0;2021-12-09T10:11:00.000Z;1;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2021-12-16 21:24:49.489 Startup conversation with host finished.
. 2021-12-16 21:25:19.676 Sending dummy command to keep session alive.
> 2021-12-16 21:25:19.676 PWD
< 2021-12-16 21:25:19.676 257 "/" is current directory.
. 2021-12-16 21:25:49.678 Sending dummy command to keep session alive.
> 2021-12-16 21:25:49.678 TYPE A
< 2021-12-16 21:25:49.678 200 Type set to A.
. 2021-12-16 21:26:19.676 Sending dummy command to keep session alive.
> 2021-12-16 21:26:19.676 REST 0
< 2021-12-16 21:26:19.676 350 Restarting at 0.
. 2021-12-16 21:26:49.676 Sending dummy command to keep session alive.
> 2021-12-16 21:26:49.676 REST 0
< 2021-12-16 21:26:49.676 350 Restarting at 0.
. 2021-12-16 21:26:49.676 Dummy directory read to keep session alive.
. 2021-12-16 21:26:49.676 Retrieving directory listing...
> 2021-12-16 21:26:49.676 TYPE A
< 2021-12-16 21:26:49.681 200 Type set to A.
> 2021-12-16 21:26:49.681 PASV
< 2021-12-16 21:26:49.686 227 Entering Passive Mode (IP).
> 2021-12-16 21:26:49.686 LIST -a
. 2021-12-16 21:26:49.686 Connecting to IP
< 2021-12-16 21:26:49.691 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
. 2021-12-16 21:26:49.695 Session ID reused
. 2021-12-16 21:26:49.696 Using TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2: ----
. 2021-12-16 21:26:49.696 TLS connection established
. 2021-12-16 21:26:49.699 08-31-21  01:50PM       <DIR>          Customers
. 2021-12-16 21:26:49.699 12-09-21  12:11PM       <DIR>          Users
. 2021-12-16 21:26:49.700 Data connection closed
< 2021-12-16 21:26:49.700 226 Transfer complete.
. 2021-12-16 21:26:49.700 Directory listing successful
. 2021-12-16 21:26:49.700 Detecting timezone difference...
. 2021-12-16 21:26:49.700 Found no file to use for detecting timezone difference
. 2021-12-16 21:26:49.700 Warning: Timezone difference was not detected yet, timestamps may be incorrect
. 2021-12-16 21:27:19.679 Sending dummy command to keep session alive.
> 2021-12-16 21:27:19.679 TYPE I
< 2021-12-16 21:27:19.679 200 Type set to I.
. 2021-12-16 21:27:49.678 Sending dummy command to keep session alive.
> 2021-12-16 21:27:49.678 TYPE I
< 2021-12-16 21:27:49.678 200 Type set to I.
. 2021-12-16 21:28:19.689 Sending dummy command to keep session alive.
> 2021-12-16 21:28:19.689 TYPE I
< 2021-12-16 21:28:19.689 200 Type set to I.
. 2021-12-16 21:28:49.696 Sending dummy command to keep session alive.
> 2021-12-16 21:28:49.696 PWD
. 2021-12-16 21:28:49.696 Disconnected from server
* 2021-12-16 21:28:49.697 (ESshFatal) **Lost connection.**
* 2021-12-16 21:28:49.697 Disconnected from server
. 2021-12-16 21:28:58.871 Connecting to ftp.x.co.il ...
. 2021-12-16 21:28:58.871 Connected with ftp.x.co.il, negotiating TLS connection...
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.871 220 Microsoft FTP Service
> 2021-12-16 21:28:58.871 AUTH TLS
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.871 234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
. 2021-12-16 21:28:58.878 Verifying certificate for "x" with fingerprint ----
. 2021-12-16 21:28:58.878 Certificate common name "*.x.co.il" matches hostname
. 2021-12-16 21:28:58.906 Certificate verified against Windows certificate store
. 2021-12-16 21:28:58.906 Using TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2: ----
. 2021-12-16 21:28:58.918 TLS connection established. Waiting for welcome message...
> 2021-12-16 21:28:58.918 USER user
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.918 331 Password required
> 2021-12-16 21:28:58.918 PASS ********
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.918 230 User logged in.
> 2021-12-16 21:28:58.918 SYST
. 2021-12-16 21:28:58.919 The server is probably running Windows, assuming that directory listing timestamps are affected by DST.
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.919 215 Windows_NT
> 2021-12-16 21:28:58.919 FEAT
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.923 211-Extended features supported:
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.923  LANG EN*
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.923  UTF8
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.923  AUTH TLS;TLS-C;SSL;TLS-P;
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.923  PBSZ
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.923  PROT C;P;
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.923  x
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.924  HOST
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.924  SIZE
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.924  MDTM
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.924  REST STREAM
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.924 211 END
> 2021-12-16 21:28:58.924 OPTS UTF8 ON
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.928 200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
> 2021-12-16 21:28:58.928 PBSZ 0
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.932 200 PBSZ command successful.
> 2021-12-16 21:28:58.932 PROT P
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.935 200 PROT command successful.
. 2021-12-16 21:28:58.954 Connected
. 2021-12-16 21:28:58.955 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2021-12-16 21:28:58.971 PWD
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.975 257 "/" is current directory.
. 2021-12-16 21:28:58.975 Changing directory to "/".
> 2021-12-16 21:28:58.975 CWD /
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.979 250 CWD command successful.
. 2021-12-16 21:28:58.979 Getting current directory name.
> 2021-12-16 21:28:58.979 PWD
< 2021-12-16 21:28:58.990 257 "/" is current directory.
. 2021-12-16 21:28:59.042 Directory content loaded from cache.
. 2021-12-16 21:28:59.061 Cached directory not reloaded.
. 2021-12-16 21:28:59.082 Retrieving directory listing...
> 2021-12-16 21:28:59.082 TYPE A
< 2021-12-16 21:28:59.086 200 Type set to A.
> 2021-12-16 21:28:59.086 PASV
< 2021-12-16 21:28:59.090 227 Entering Passive Mode (IP).
> 2021-12-16 21:28:59.090 LIST -a
. 2021-12-16 21:28:59.091 Connecting to ip
< 2021-12-16 21:28:59.096 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
. 2021-12-16 21:28:59.100 Session ID reused
. 2021-12-16 21:28:59.100 Using TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2: ----
. 2021-12-16 21:28:59.100 TLS connection established
. 2021-12-16 21:28:59.104 08-31-21  01:50PM       <DIR>          Customers
. 2021-12-16 21:28:59.104 12-09-21  12:11PM       <DIR>          Users
< 2021-12-16 21:28:59.105 226 Transfer complete.
. 2021-12-16 21:28:59.105 Data connection closed
. 2021-12-16 21:28:59.105 Directory listing successful
. 2021-12-16 21:28:59.105 Detecting timezone difference...
. 2021-12-16 21:28:59.105 Found no file to use for detecting timezone difference
. 2021-12-16 21:28:59.105 Warning: Timezone difference was not detected yet, timestamps may be incorrect
. 2021-12-16 21:28:59.105 xxx
. 2021-12-16 21:28:59.105 xxx
. 2021-12-16 21:28:59.105 xxx
. 2021-12-16 21:28:59.131 Startup conversation with host finished.
. 2021-12-16 21:29:29.706 Sending dummy command to keep session alive.
> 2021-12-16 21:29:29.706 TYPE I
< 2021-12-16 21:29:29.706 200 Type set to I.
. 2021-12-16 21:29:30.427 Disconnected from server
```

Comment: Give us an exact error that you are getting. Or even better a session log file. And a log file from WinSCP GUI that shows a successful upload from the same local machine, using the same credentials to the same remote folder. Are you sure you have identified the problem correctly? Shouldn't the `-Destination` be `/users/users's folder/shaon/` (slash at the end)? Or isn't the account chrooted? => Shouldn't the `-Destination` be `/`?

Comment: OK, the logs are here.

Thank you for the answer by the way.

Comment: Your PowerShell session does not even get to a point where any path would matter. It seems that your credentials are wrong. Double check them. Actually, the `SessionOptions.Password` is a plain text password. Did you try to hard-code plain text password for a test, before doing your secure string magic?